# Excel JS Add-Ins: Storing non-sensitive data in a hidden worksheet vs in workbook settings

Tags: office-js, custom-functions-excel

Our legacy Excel add-in stores some non-sensitive workbook-related data inside a "very hidden" worksheet. We are developing a port of the add-in using Office JS, and are weighing the pros and cons of storing the data in a "very hidden" worksheet versus in workbook settings.

1. Is it bad to store non-sensitive non-PII data in a "very hidden" worksheet. If yes, could you please clarify the reason?
2. Are the settings accessible through VBA?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [workbook.customXmlParts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbook?view=excel-js-preview#customxmlparts). Custom XML Parts are accessible only programmatically. Thus, there is no need to hide anything from the end user.

The JavaScript API is similar to the VBA API. So yes - you can access the same part from both VBA and JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Zlatko. Can I conclude that there is nothing bad with storing non-sensitive data in a "very hidden" worksheet, except for it is not as convenient and well-suited?